# Sum column in list in list for each element

Tags: python, list, sum, 2d

For a list of lists, is there some way of summing a column for each specific element in the list (using python). An example...

```
l=[['A1','1','2'],['A1','1','2'],['A1','3','3'],['B1','1','2'],['B1','5','5'],[...]]
```

Now sum the **first column only** for A1's, B1's etc and get the desired output as...

```
sumA1=5
sumB1=6
sumC1.......
```

Now list values may change so I don't want reference to "A1, B1..". It may become A3, B4....so the best way would be to sum according to index[0] (the number/ type of columns wont change).
The code I have atm is just a simple list comprehension that sums all of column 1 regardless of whether A1, B1, etc..

```
for i in l:
    total = sum(float(i[1]) for i in l if i[1])
```

Considering there will always be the same number of items for each "A1, B1.." let's say 10, an alternative would be to sum every 10 numbers in i[1] but then I'd need to be able to say 'the sum of the 1st 10 numbers are for A1, the sum of the 2nd 10 numbers is B2, etc'. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

Group the items on the first column into a dictionary; a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes that a little easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sums = defaultdict(int)

for tup in l:
    sums[tup[0]] += int(tup[1])
```

`defaultdict` simply calls the passed-in factory to produce a default value if a key isn't present  (`int` in this case, producing a `0`):

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['foo']
0
```

Demo:

```
>>> l=[['A1','1','2'],['A1','1','2'],['A1','3','3'],['B1','1','2'],['B1','5','5']]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> sums = defaultdict(int)
>>> for tup in l:
...     sums[tup[0]] += int(tup[1])
... 
>>> sums
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'B1': 6, 'A1': 5})
```

Then printing the sums is as simple as:

```
for key in sorted(sums):
    print 'sum{}={}'.format(key, sums[key])
```

If your input list is *sorted*, use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sums = {key: sum(int(t[1]) for t in group) for key, group in groupby(l, key=itemgetter(0))}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> {key: sum(int(t[1]) for t in group) for key, group in groupby(l, key=itemgetter(0))}
{'B1': 6, 'A1': 5}
```

In fact, with a sorted list and `groupby` you can switch straight to printing:

```
for key, group in groupby(l, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print 'sum{}={}'.format(key, sum(t[1]) for t in group))
```

Without external modules I'd just go for a dictionary; this is going to be slower than either of the above options:

```
sums = {}

for tup in l:
    sums[tup[0]] = sums.get(tup[0], 0) + int(tup[1])
```

or, for the sorted variant:

```
sum, last = 0, l[0][0]
for tup in l:
    key = tup[0]
    if last != key and sum:
        print 'sum{}={}'.format(last, sum)
        sum, last = 0, key
    sum += int(tup[1])
if sum:
    print 'sum{}={}'.format(key, sum)
```

Comment: These look good, but is defaultdict necessary or can it be done in a for loop?

Comment: I'm blind. Just noticed the for loop. So what does defaultdict actually do if the item are already sorted?

Comment: @Op.Ivy: Added clarifications; if your input list is sorted, don't bother with `defaultdict` and go straight for `groupby`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: great explanation, that clears it up. Can this also be achieved without itertools? I'm trying to learn the basics without using modules. appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = [["a",1,2],["a",2,3],["b",45,2]]
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for itm in a:
...    my_dict[itm[0]].append(itm)
...
>>> for k,v in my_dict.items():
...    print "Sum %s:%s"%(k,sum(zip(*v)[1]))
...
Sum a:3
Sum b:45
```